# css selector tool for craeting css path automatically

Tags: css-selectors

I am working on Selenium currently. I stuck at a point where i want to generate CSS path element automatically. In Firefox, we can use Firebug. But problem is that we have to choose element manually and copy n paste the resulted CSS path. I am able to get some reference of given element then using that reference i am building CSS path. But problem is that its not reliable. Here, what i want to do is just give URL of any site then element name like for example links. It should be able to catch all the links and calculate the CSS path.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [CSSSelector tool](http://ashishkhadse.wordpress.com/csscreater-tool/)

Brief description is given by author. It will fulfill your need to great extends.